# Chef recipe: syntax error,unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ':'

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Can someone please take a look at the below code block and let me know what is wrong in this

```
%w"#{zookeeper_ensemble}".each_with_index do |ip, index|
  if node['ipaddress']?("#{ip}") 
    template "#{zookeeper_data}/myid" do
      source "myid.erb"
      owner zookeeper_user
      group zookeeper_user
      variables(
        :myid=> "#{index}"
      )
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting following error

```
SyntaxError
-----------
/root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/zookeeper/recipes/default.rb:69: syntax error,     unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ':'
template "#{zookeeper_data}/myid" do
        ^
/root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/zookeeper/recipes/default.rb:78: syntax error,      unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: What are you intending with `%w"#{zookeeper_ensemble}"`? In Ruby things like `"#{ip}"` are usually exactly the same as `ip`, or more formally `ip.to_s` if you're concerned about casting to string. It's cargo-cult anti-patttern to see single strings interpolated like that pervasively.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that `node['ipaddress']?("#{ip}")` is not valid Ruby and from there the syntax is trashed, so you might want to fix that line up. I'd expect `node['ipaddress'].x?(...)` where `x?` is a method, or `node['ipaddress'] ? (...) : (...)` if it's part of a ternary.

Comment: Thanks for your edit and comments. What I want to do is create and array attribute containing few ip adrresses and read those ipaddresses in my recipe and create a file myid containing index of the ipaddress in array.

Comment: You probably need to amend your question with a sample of the data structure you're working with.

Comment: Why -2 ??? I am new to chef, ruby So there are lots of possibility of simple mistakes and I hope experts should edit the question/comment/answer If newbies are not clear about their situation. Should not degrade their initial reputation at least :(

Comment: Being new to Ruby is not the problem here, we all started at the beginning. What's attracting down-votes is you haven't taken the time to get a good Ruby reference and familiarize yourself with the syntax instead of just throwing code at Stack Overflow in the hopes someone else will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it my self 
off course @Codrenger's answer gave me direction. Thanks

```
default['zookeeper']['cluster_ips'] = {'1.1.1.1' => 1, '2.2.2.2' => 2}
.
.
.

node['zookeeper']['cluster_ips'].each do |ip, id|
if node["ipaddress"] == ip
 template "#{zookeeper_data}/myid" do
           source "myid.erb"
           owner zookeeper_user
           group zookeeper_user
           variables myid: id   
     end
end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably meant:

```
zookeeper_ensemble.each_with_index do |ip, index|
  if node['ipaddress'] == ip 
    template "#{zookeeper_data}/myid" do
      source "myid.erb"
      owner zookeeper_user
      group zookeeper_user
      variables myid: index
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I changed my code to
`%w"#{zookeeper_ensemble}".each_with_index {|ip, index|

      if node["ipaddress"] == ip
        template "#{zookeeper_data}/myid" do
         source "myid.erb"
         owner zookeeper_user
         group zookeeper_user
         variables myid: index 
            end
  end
}`

Attribute declaration in attribute file
`default['zookeeper']['cluster_ips'] = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2']`
and a local variable declaration recipe is
`zookeeper_ensemble = node['zookeeper']['cluster_ips']`
When I run this code I do not see any error but nothing happens as well.

Comment: What I want to do is create and array attribute containing few ip adrresses and read those ipaddresses in my recipe and create a file myid containing index of the ipaddress in array if the current ip in array matches with the current node's ip. Could you please help me to achieve this?